# Movie with execution by cartoonish organ harvesting machine

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a movie in which, after some space flight and perhaps in a hanger, the protagonist and his love interest are queued up to be executed. This is done by being pressed up against a wall with saws cutting along comical outlines of organs.

Most of the people in line are apathetic and I think maybe they were being executed for illegal immigration rather than crime. There is a guard ushering them forward and we see someone else get executed/harvested before dropping down a hatch in the floor. I think the protagonist escapes by entering the chamber with the love interest and dodging the saws before falling with her down the hatch.

I don't remember this as being a very good movie and maybe I just caught this one scene on TV but its stuck with me.

Comment: Can you [edit] in when you may have seen this? Can you remember any other plot points about it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is pilot movie for Lexx, [I Worship his Divine Shadow](http://lexx.wikia.com/wiki/I_Worship_His_Shadow).

Convicted criminals are put in for processing and have their organs removed (on a conveyor belt) for inclusion in the "Protein Bank"

[image]

Comment: And the crimes they're convicted of are pretty obviously not stuff you'd expect a death penalty for -- being late to work too many times, for instance.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Your lax attitude toward compliance has been duly noted and may be used against you in a court of surgery, citizen.

Comment: Might also note that citizens (in line for execution or otherwise) are told the harvested organ go to a transplant program, when in fact they were being fed the the Gigashadow.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - You have incurred 5 de-merits. Please report to correction centre number 40

Comment: Wait, *I'm* not Stanley Ipkiss, I'm *looking for* Stanley Ipkiss.  Guess he's not here.

Comment: I love the way the mayor sings, "there's a light".

Answer (score 18):

Might be not movie, but a series - the first episode of "[LEXX - The Dark Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx)" had pretty much what you described. TV Tropes (obligatory warning, the link will eat your time and brain) [lists organ harvesting in LEXX](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/LEXX) as example for the "Cruel and Unusual Death" trope.

The Episode is on youtube, the [scene starts about 24:50](https://youtu.be/OFRe4nl8ugM?t=1489).